# Hibernate merge method persists the copy of entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Merge method creates copy of the entity and persist that copy, so here my question why it needs to create a copy? why not persist the same object directly?

This question is related to design, why a copy is persisted not that entity itself? So I think this question needs to be reopened.

Comment: @Jens only copy is created mentioned over there, no explanation why the copy is needed.

Comment: `If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X'.` Here its not mentioned why a copy is needed?

Comment: I have got the answer for this question, like why a copy needs to be created.