# clazz_ attribute in hibernate query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

In Hibernate table per concrete class strategy when fetched with super class following query is generated:

```
SELECT vehicle0_.VEHICLE_ID    AS VEHICLE_ID1_2_,
  vehicle0_.MANUFACTURER       AS MANUFACTURER2_2_,
  vehicle0_.PASSENGER_CAPACITY AS PASSENGER_CAPACITY1_0_,
  vehicle0_.LOAD_CAPACITY      AS LOAD_CAPACITY1_1_,
  vehicle0_.clazz_             AS clazz_
FROM
  (SELECT VEHICLE_ID,
    MANUFACTURER,
    PASSENGER_CAPACITY,
    NULL AS LOAD_CAPACITY,
    1    AS clazz_
  FROM PassengerVehicle
  UNION ALL
  SELECT VEHICLE_ID,
    MANUFACTURER,
    NULL AS PASSENGER_CAPACITY,
    LOAD_CAPACITY,
    2 AS clazz_
  FROM TransportationVehicle
  ) vehicle0_
```

`vehicle0_.clazz_` is selected in query which is not there in table nor in class, what is this `clazz_` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's **inheritance discriminator**.

When you joined your subclass with super class, do avoid the confusion while instantiating from the result set, hibernate internally uses the column `'clazz'`.

Comment: I thought inheritance discriminator is needed when working with single table strategy, this column is added while working with joined and table_per_class strategy. In both of the strategy it does select from separate table then why this column is needed?

Comment: There are two more questions that are really putting me in confusion. It would be nice and helpful for me if you can answer those question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516409/difference-hibernate-with-dialect-and-without-dialect and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472739/hibernate-merge-method-persists-the-copy-of-entity

Comment: @eatSleepCode It selects that is fine, but which subclass needs to instantiate with hibernate ? That's the information /need

Comment: Thanks allot for the answer.

Comment: So we need to add Discriminator for this table @eatSleepCode ?